# Open a file by its name using argument in Java

Tags: java, file, io, try-catch

I'm able to read a file by specifying the file path (which is in my src project) but I'm trying to read or open it by providing its name when the user is prompted by the command line in the first argument.

```
File fileName = new File("/Users/blad/Documents/CS2/Labs/Project01/input.txt");
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileName);
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){

                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The name of the file is "input.txt" Is there a way to approach that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using these codes for a different approach and see if this would be able to fix your problem

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Users/OCMEngineering1/Desktop/library/library/textfile/student.txt");
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it will read file name and then use it to create file object.If you want to read multiple file name use a while loop.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is the filename?");
String input = in.nextLine();
File fileName = new File(input);
```

Comment: How can I check if the name I input is there? In the folder project

Comment: do  isFile(); If file exist it will give you true

Comment: eg - new File("path/to/file.txt").isFile();

Comment: did the solution worked?